# Combinations of integers exercise

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Kindly help me to answer this:

Suppose five integers are chosen successively at random between 0 and 13, inclusive. Find the probability that:

(Round your answer to four decimal places if necessary.)

a. they are all different

b. not more than 2 are the same?

Comment: What have you done so far to try and get to the solution?

Comment: It is kind of a duplicate of this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2904829/probability-four-random-integers-between-0-9-that-not-more-than-two-are-the-s?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The first can be anything.  The chance the second does not match the first is $\frac {13}{14}$, then the chance the third does not match either is $\frac {13}{14}$ and so on, giving a chance of no match as $\frac {13\cdot 12 \cdot 11 \cdot 10}{14^4}$

For the second, compute the chance of exactly one match then add to the first. 
 You can choose the locations of the match in ${5 \choose 2}=10$ ways.  You have $\frac 1{14}$ chance that those locations match, then $\frac {13\cdot 12 \cdot 11 }{14^3}$  chance the other three are different from the one at those locations and each other.  The chance comes out the same, so you can just double the first result.

Comment: The second question asks for the probability that not more than two are the same, so you have to add the two probabilities you found.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig:  I missed that.  We can just add my second to the first.  Updated.  Thanks

Comment: Can you detail the solution on letter B? Thank you so much

Comment: Say you choose the first and third that are the two that match.  There are $10$ ways to choose the pair.  Then the first can be anything and you have $\frac 1{14}$ chance that the third matches.  Then you have to fill in the other three slots with numbers that do not match that one or each other.